# UseDirectoryBrowser middleware working without adding AddDirectoryBrowser in .NET Core. Active

Tags: asp.net-core

I place app.UseDirectoryBrowser() in my Configure Method (or so called Middleware). Nothing else. No service. Default / Empty template. Then also I am able to browse the directory via Visual Studio, via IIS, and via CLI. So what is the purpose of services.AddDirectoryBrowser().

Here is the link of M/S Site.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Where they specify Enable directory browsing with:

AddDirectoryBrowser in Startup.ConfigureServices.
UseDirectoryBrowser in Startup.Configure.
But I didn't add "AddDirectoryBrowser " and still able to browse the directory.

Answer (score 0):

that's really odd as the documents said `Directory browsing is disabled by default for security reasons`. That means we can't view the project static files folder without enabling the configuration. And could you pls offer more details such as framework version, startup file or something else?

Here's my test result, I created a default asp.net core 3.1 mvc project and after adding `services.AddDirectoryBrowser();` and `app.UseDirectoryBrowser();` I can browse my static file folder but without them, I failed. I tested in vs and I deploy with the iis express.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Tiny Wang,
You have commented app.UseDirectoryBrowser from your configure method. That's why it is not working. My only concern is what is the use of services.AddDirectoryBrowser(). 
Please try to comment only on service and not the middleware. It will work without adding service i.e Services.AddDirectoryBrowser()

Comment: @AmitRawat Hi, thanks for your reply, I tested according to your saying and it's true that it still work without `services.AddDirectoryBrowser()`, and I think it's also a normal situation as [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.directorybrowserserviceextensions.adddirectorybrowser?view=aspnetcore-5.0#returns) said `The IServiceCollection so that additional calls can be chained.` That means if you don't call this service in other place, it's really useless to set this line code in ConfigureServices

Comment: And there's also a saying in the document `AddDirectoryBrowser must be called when the EnableDirectoryBrowsing property value is true`, and it really work when I comment `services.AddDirectoryBrowser()`, I assume it has been included in mvc service. In other words, I assume that the source code of `services.AddMvc()` includes `services.AddDirectoryBrowser()`.